# How to convert Spring Integration application in Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration and i have done a sample application. But i have used XML for configuration. I want to use annotations and do the same application.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Below is my Configuration file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd">


<!-- CHANNEL -->
<int:channel id="requestChannel" />
<int:channel id="outputChannel" />
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
    reply-channel="outputChannel" supported-methods="GET"
    path="/welcome/{name}" payload-expression="#pathVariables.name">

    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator ref="welcomeEndpoint"
    method="get" input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="outputChannel" />
```

Below is the service class

```
@Component
public class WelcomeEndpoint {
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

public Message<?> get(Message<String> msg) {
    String name = msg.getPayload();
    // Log
    log.info("Request with name = " + name);

    // Get currentTime
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String currentTime = dtf.format(now);

    String strMsg = "Hello " + name + "! " + "Welcome to Spring Integration with Spring Boot!";

    HelloMsg returnMsg = new HelloMsg(strMsg, currentTime);

    return MessageBuilder.withPayload(returnMsg)
        .copyHeadersIfAbsent(msg.getHeaders())
        .setHeader("http_statusCode", HttpStatus.OK)
        .build();
}
```

}

POJO

```
public class HelloMsg {

private String msg;
private String currentTime;

public HelloMsg(){}

public HelloMsg(String msg, String currentTime){
    this.msg = msg;
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
}

public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}
public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
public String getCurrentTime() {
    return currentTime;
}
public void setCurrentTime(String currentTime) {
    this.currentTime = currentTime;
}
```

}

Spring Boot Application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:integration.xml")
public class SpringIntegrationApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationApplication.class, args);
}
```

}

Comment: Refer:Java DSL: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#inboundAdapters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the reference manual [Java DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/java-dsl.html), [Finding Class Names for Java and DSL Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#_finding_class_names_for_java_and_dsl_configuration) and [annotation support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations).